# Render custom template for every user in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am trying to build a website where users can create a shop on my website and they can also specify their shop theme.

`https://example.com/<dynamic-shop-name>`
This will be shop URL. Like Shopify

Every shop's theme name will be stored in DB. I will get the theme name before the shop's page is rendered.

**So my question is how can render the shop page template based on the theme name?**

one possible solution is conditionally render based on the theme name but if I have 50/60+ themes then it will affect page render time.

Thanks. Your suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: im not sure what your templates look like but you could create an object with the theme names as keys and the template (styles?) as values. when you then have a theme name, you can just access its template like this: `templateObj[themeName]`.

Comment: thanks. if I create a template as react component then do I have to set the component as object value? [my template will be different e-commerce template]

Comment: yes. if its always the same component with different props it might not make sense to create the object (but rather differentiate over generic props f.ex.).but if it's a different component for each theme, then yes.